# Automatically click a dialog button when the dialog appears

Tags: kubuntu, automation

Back in the day when I was still using Windows, there was a program that ran in the system tray that would watch for a dialog/window to open (by title or progid), the click a specific button (or send the appropriate key combination, e.g. "ALT+S") on that dialog.

I know that with AutoKey, I can use window.wait_for_exist, but it waits the entire timeout before executing the action.

How do I make the next action happen the moment the window becomes available?

Or is there such a program already out there for Kubuntu?

Or could I make xdotool do it?

Edit: more information

Comment: probably xdotool.    id=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --name "$name")   .... xdotool windowactivate --sync $id key  --clearmodifiers  --delay 100 ctrl+s  or something.  make script loop for , say 1 second delay     sleep 0.1 for 1/10th of a second. to get the "name" maybe run a busy poll for xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname.   maybe with xprop | grep WM_CLASS or xprop | awk '/PID/ {print $3}' you can click on the dialogue and get id...